# Adding tasks to an existing task collection does not update the index

Tags: vb.net, ms-project

I am trying to add a task to an existing task collection by using the ActiveProject.Tasks.Add("name",*index*) but after that all the tasks after the *index* keep the same index as before the add.

So when i am trying to add many different tasks some of them are not at the good position because the index are not accurate anymore.

Someone have an idea how to update the tasks index that follow the one i just added? I can't even modify the index of an existing task because the index property is a read-only.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally i used the ID property of the task and it works, this property updates when we add tasks to the collection.